# Different Result between SQL-developer and C# code

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, odac

I need to get partition information on some table in oracle

this query:

`select HIGH_VALUE from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'`

return this result:

- TO_DATE(' 2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
- TO_DATE(' 2018-08-03 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
- TO_DATE(' 2000-01-04 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
- TO_DATE(' 2018-08-09 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')

but in C# code result is a string array with 4 empty string item

```
const string query = "select HIGH_VALUE from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'";
var infos = context
               .Database
               .SqlQuery<string>(query)
               .ToArray();
```

why results are different?

Comment: `HIGH_VALUE` is of type `LONG`. Check how to select `LONG` in `C#`

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, HIGH_VALUE is a LONG data type. You need PL SQL to retrieve the value and use it:

```
DECLARE
  v_high_value varchar2(32762);
BEGIN
  select  high_value into  v_high_value
     from all_tab_partitions where table_name = 'MyTable'
     and rownum<=1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'first partition high value is :'||v_high_value);
END;
/
```

You can write an oracle function that does the conversion and use it in C#.